# 'active' class added to link disappears when drilling down into the section

Tags: ember.js, routes

**Templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li>{{#linkTo 'projects'}}Projects{{/linkTo}}</li>
            <li>{{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="projects">
    <div class="l-wrap">
        <table class="list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name</th>               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each model}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{#linkTo 'project' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}               
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>
    <div>
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="project">
    <p>Project Details for {{name}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{description}}</p>
</script>
```

**Routes 1**

```
  this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'});   
  });
```

**Routes 2**

```
  this.resource('projects');
  this.resource('project', { path: 'project/:project_id'});
```

**Problem**

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on Projects link it should display a list of projects. And when I click on the Project Name in the list, the list should disappear and the details of the clicked project should be displayed.

In **Route 1** arrangement, the list of projects does not disappear. So I can't use it.

In **Route 2** arrangement, the list of projects disappears and everything is as I expect except for one thing - the CSS 'active' class from Projects link disappears. I am still inside the Projects section, so I do not want the 'active' class to go away.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using the [`index` route](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#sts=The%20Index%20Route) of the `projects` route to show your initial list.

Use the same router as your **Route 1**:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'});   
  });
});
```

but configure the `project` template to only contain an outlet:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="projects">
    <p>Projects</p>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Then move your original `projects` template into `projects/index`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="projects/index">
    <p>Projects Index</p>
    <div class="l-wrap">
        <table class="list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name</th>               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each model}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{#linkTo 'project' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}               
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>

</script>
```

Now you link to `projects` you will enter `projects.index`, and when you link to a specific project it will replace the `projects` `{{outlet}}` with the `project` detail route.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/704/edit)

Note: the reason the **Route 2** does not keep the active class is that you have defined 2 parallel route paths, so when you switch to the other one the app thinks you have moved to a different area of the app.  Ember's router uses the route nesting to determine which links to keep `active`.

Hint: enable logging of transitions to help know what routes you are entering

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

Comment: Instead of setting ProjectsIndexRoute's model to the parent model by writing return this.modelFor('projects'); one can simply write return App.Project.find(); here and remove ProjectsRoute completely. Would that be less correct semantically? What would be the drawbacks?

Comment: Yeah, that works too! The `projects` route is the parent of both the `index` and `project`, so if for some reason you needed the full list in both of them, it might be useful to get it a single time in the parent.